# Node JS Webpack Build Failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to keep the Backend project I developed with Node JS as Build and keep it as 1 HTML file on my server as Webpack. I am developing with nodemon, no problem, but according to my configuration, the "NPM RUN BUILD" dwelling does not work. Could cause the problem?

30 different errors return, this is one. All of them write other library information like this.
**"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/ Users / ugurcanalyuz / Projects / Ekartex / ekartex_backend / node_modules / body-parser / lib'"**

webpack.config.js

```
 const path = require("path");
    module.exports = {
        entry: './server.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './dist',
            compress: true,
            port: 3200
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const users = require("./src/routers/users");
app.use(users);

app.listen(3200, () => {
    console.log("Sistem açık");
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "exxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like, some of the packages are missing.
Could you briefly explain, how you setup your Project?

Comment: @YannickEich While setting up the project, I first made use of the "npm init --yes" command. Then I installed related Webpack libraries and added "express". This is such an empty project.

Comment: Which commands did you use to install all the required Packages?

Comment: I installed "--save" and "express and webpack" plugins. Among the modules that fail, there is "fs, zlib, path, crypto, buffer". I also installed these the error count dropped to 14 but I still get the same errors. "Can't resolve" error for modules I installed. @YannickEich

Comment: Could you setup an new Project, which you directly try to build?

Comment: I can install. Should I add the "express" module again? @YannickEich

Comment: This time you should follow the Official Express Instructions.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: Okay, I'll come back. @YannickEich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the following command, inside you command line (/terminal):

```
npm i zlib
```

Comment: I didn't use zlib anywhere, but I did what it said 3 errors were missing. Do I have to do this? As a result, I just added "express" and "webpack" to the blank project.

Answer (score 1):

devServer option is for client-side.  for node.js you need to add

```
 target: "node",
```

and also for better performance

```
 const nodeWebExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
 // add this property to webpack config object
 externals: [nodeWebExternals()],
```